# Parsing selected value in drop down to next page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to parse the current selected value of a drop-down to the next page via a http request - so the value selected is parsed via the url to the next page.

The form drop-down looks like this:

```
<form name="sortby">
    <select id="order_by" name="order_by" onchange="sortBy()">
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'choose') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="choose">Sort By</option>
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'OVERALL_VALUE') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="OVERALL_VALUE">Most Popular</option>
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'PRICE') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="PRICE">Price (low to high)</option>
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'PRICE_REVERSE') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="PRICE_REVERSE">Price (high to low)</option>
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'QUALITY') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="QUALITY">Rating</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here is where I want to post the selected value to the next page - via button:

```
echo "&nbsp;<button><a href=\"$PHP_SELF?go&s=$news&cacheKey=$cacheKey&cacheLocation=$cacheLocation&customerSessionId=$customerSessionId&name=" . strval($_GET['name']) . "&arrival=" . strval($_GET['arrival']) . "&departure=" . strval($_GET['departure']) . "&rooms=" . strval($_GET['rooms']) . "&numberOfGuests=" . strval($_GET['guests']) . "&order_by=" . $_GET['order_by'] . "\">Next &gt;&gt;</a></button>";
```

So where it says &order_by=" . $_GET['order_by'] . is where I want to parse the current selected value to the next page. But I don't get the value in the url with this Get method - what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass variables to construct an `SQL` statement through the URL ?!?!

Comment: it seems that you need to use Javascript, if you want this to change without you using forms .. However if you want to use forms, then use hidden inputs for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `http_build_query()` to clean that up. Use it like this:

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
//OUTPUT: foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor

echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');
//OUTPUT: foo=bar&amp;baz=boom&amp;cow=milk&amp;php=hypertext+processor
```

Alternatively, with JS you can do this:

```
function getCurrentParams() {
    var url = document.URL;
    var url_split = url.split("?");
    var params = url_split[1];
    return params;
}

function urlToObj(url) {
    var obj = {};
    var pairs = url.split('&');
    for (i in pairs) {
        var split = pairs[i].split('=');
        obj[decodeURIComponent(split[0])] = decodeURIComponent(split[1]);
    }
    return obj;
}

function getQuery(e){ // will fire on button click
    var value = $("#order_by").val();
    var params_string = getCurrentParams();
    var get_params_obj = urlToObj(params_string);
    get_params_obj.orderBy= value;
    var params = $.param(get_params_obj);
    alert(params);
    location.href = "http://youbaseurl.com?"+params;
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="return getQuery(this)"></button>
```

Comment: Have a hard time understanding how to use your JS example. How do I get  the value retrieved with the JS into the url call in the button ? @CodeGodie

Comment: it does work to the extend that I get alerted the value from the sort by drop down. But it does not go to the url I get fra the Alert. How do I get the function getQuery to actually go to the url created ?

Comment: you have to force a `location.href`. i updated the code

Answer (score 0):

just put a submit button instead of  tag and click on it . it will send the selected value via get method. and make sure u define action attribute in form element

```
        <form action="">
        <select>
       .....................  
       </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: This will not work, because he needs all the other data in his query. To make it work without JS, he would need to use many hidden inputs.